# Python: Strange behaviour of an iterable in and out of a context manager (cause of ValueError in audioread.audio_open & librosa)

Tags: python, audio, iterable, librosa, contextmanager

I am trying to investigate a reason for kinda strange behaviour of an iterator within a context manager. I am missing something here, maybe you will be able to explain.

Nothing changes, same iterable object but iteration stops working if out of CM for some reason.

Minimal code sample:
(requires an mp3 file at 'af_path' and ffmpeg binary in a project folder to run)

```
import inspect
from collections.abc import Iterable
def ar_preloader(af_path):
    """creates audioread object"""
    import audioread.ffdec
    # !!! ffmpeg binary backend must exist in the project folder
    with audioread.audio_open(af_path) as m:
        test = m
        print(type(test), inspect.isgenerator(test), isinstance(test, Iterable))
        print(next(iter(test)), 1111)

    # print(next(iter(test)), 2222)
    # print(type(test), inspect.isgenerator(test), isinstance(test, Iterable))
```

Then if you comment 2 print statements in context manager and uncomment last two statements outside, you'll get StopIteration exception.

```
import inspect
from collections.abc import Iterable
def ar_preloader(af_path):
    """creates audioread object"""
    import audioread.ffdec
    # !!! ffmpeg binary backend must exist in the project folder
    with audioread.audio_open(af_path) as m:
        test = m
        # print(type(test), inspect.isgenerator(test), isinstance(test, Iterable))
        # print(next(iter(test)), 1111)

    print(next(iter(test)), 2222)
    print(type(test), inspect.isgenerator(test), isinstance(test, Iterable))
```

Despite it's still an iterable and same audioread object (test.channels, test.samplerate, test.duration attributes still work).

What is even more strange, if you leave both ...1111 and ...2222 statements at once, it will work as should, i.e. first next(...) inside gives 1 frame, 2nd (outside) gives 2nd frame and so on, i.e. now that iterator could be iterated. Nevertheless, I can't leave out first anyhow.

I ran into this issue when I were trying to debug an error in librosa module. Its docs describe audioread context manager approach only but I wanted to create a function that loads an existing audioread object, i.e. not by path.

```
def l_analysis_o(afo):
    import librosa
    lo = librosa.load(afo)
    # each librosa object is a tuple, (y=array, sr=sampling rate)

l_analysis_o(ar_preloader('path_to_mp3'))
```

I want to split up audioread object creation by path and further librosa analysis like that but transfer of an audioread object to librosa out of audioread.audio_open() context manager results in a error:

> ValueError: Input signal length=0 is too small to resample from 44100->22050

Librosa uses __audioread_load function from \librosa\core\audio.py with a for-loop inside:

```
for frame in input_file:
....
y.append(frame)
....
return y
```

So if input_file is not an iterable (doesn't have iter method), there is NO frames from it and the resulting y-list is empty (that causes further errors).

Comment: [`ffmpeg` backend's `__exit__` calls `close`](https://github.com/beetbox/audioread/blob/ee68207c86ac6d2ca67cf0e23d6f0732f8aadbbb/audioread/ffdec.py#L317), might have something to do with that.

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah, I am trying to understand what could be wrong in their close method.
They state it as 
"""Close the ffmpeg process used to perform the decoding.""" and kill processes 
which shouldn't harm anything which has just been decoded to binary. I can't even understand how to simulate this behaviour and interfere with iterable in __exit__ so that it couldn't be iterated elsewhere.

Comment: *" I can't even understand how to simulate this behaviour and interfere with iterable in exit so that it couldn't be iterated elsewhere"* It's enough for `__exit__` to consume the iterator that `__enter__` returns for it to not be iterable outside of the `with` block, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DeepSpace2/7ddb1c788b67916eac5a407e919e965c)

Comment: ... or this [live demo](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=class%20Foo%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.iter%20%3D%20iter%28%5B1%5D%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__enter__%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20self.iter%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__exit__%28self,%20exc_type,%20exc_val,%20exc_tb%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20next%28self.iter%29%0A%0A%0Awith%20Foo%28%29%20as%20foo%3A%0A%20%20%20%20pass%0A%0Aprint%28next%28foo%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=13&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D)

Comment: @DeepSpace
Yeah, you're right, it could be like that but my iterator (decoded mp3 file) is huge, i.e. not really close to a single element. There's probably something else that 1st next call does here, other than just iterating.